# Displaying listview containing images - directly from url or pre-downloaded?

Tags: listview, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms app to handling spare parts warehouse. I have a class 'Part' that contains all related properties as well as part's image. For the moment, there's around 3000 unique parts and almost all have images attached. The data and images are being delivered by web api service built in ASP.NET web api. 
Now I'd like to add a form to browse the parts' list containing their images. There will be also a search box to filter the list by keywords. I would like it to be as fast as possible and hence I'm wondering which approach should I stick to:

1. Easier - loading all items directly from web api when user opens the form.
2. Loading all parts to sqlite local db asynchronously on app launch + downloading the images and storing them somewhere in the memory. I could only e.g. load those parts that have been created or modified after last sync date. Thanks to this, there would be something in a form of data mirror stored locally and it would be asynchronously updated on app launch.

Second option might be an overkill, I don't know, I have no experience with similar problem. On the other hand, preloading everything and displaying/searching it from memory will probably be a lot more performant. The app I build is used by small, closed group and the parts don't change too often. Besides, I expect the parts' form to be browsed/queried multiple times during single session and internet coverage isn't perfect there. All this seem to also be in favor of option 2, but I'd like to learn your opionion.

Comment: "I'd like to learn your opinion" - SO discourages questions that solicit opinions.  But you might want to check out https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I haven't heard about this library.. Definitely worth considering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly asynchronous methods must be your friend in this jounery to get a good performance.

There are tips I would like to share with you as I have same experience with news app which have more pictures and endless news :D

1- glideX: this library will provide a very good image performance
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/glidex-fast-images-android/

2- Compile binding: with this new option in Xamarin Forms you will avoid any headache from binding and your list will be faster in runtime, but remember you will suffering from more build time. "Depending on your pc performance"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings

3- CollectionView: depend on profiling performance between listview and CollectionView, CollectionView wins, but remember to set item sizing to measure first item if you have same data template
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/

4- Pagination: you can use load data incrementally option in CollectionView to create this pagination either data loaded locally or from rest api.

5- Rx: if you want a really good search experience you must go to Rx.net either you use local data or rest api call.

6-Asynchronous: you must use async methods as you can "but with good practice", to avoid deadlocks.

Finally I can't told you which best choice between load all data then query from it, list all items in one time or load with pagination pattern from api but if you follow tips above you will get awesome list with great performance.

Comment: Thanks for all the hints, it's more than what I've expected.  Having checked GlideX I see it's faster than ffImageLoading but the latter has more options. I think I'll first go with GlideX and images loaded from server, depending on its performance I might switch to ffImageLoading later. I see it doesn't support placeholder/loading images, but maybe there's a workaround. I definitely must get my hands dirty before judging which approach is better

Comment: Your welcome , and regard to FfImage you can create custom control and add grid with image and whatever you want to use to shoiwa loading like activity indicator or gif, good luck